# How to add attributes (id for example) to options of Zend_Form_Element_Select?

Tags: zend-framework

I need to add custom attributes `(id, class)` to options of `Zend_Form_Element_Select`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in an "attribs" array when instantiating the element. For example:

```
    $form->addElement('select', 'type', array(
        'label' => 'Label',
        'multioptions' => $some_array,
        'attribs' => array('class' => 'selector', 'id' => 'whatever')
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to add ids to select's options. Option would be implementing your own viewHelper and adding this functionality. But generally it's not possible.